# Unbound breakpoint in VS Code (Chrome debug session, Vanilla JS application (Node backend))

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

VSCode debugger with chrome is working with my react projects, but with vanilla JS projects breakpoints are unbound.

All the solutions for this issue seem to be for frameworks. I cannot locate a fix for plain JS projects.

Launch.json

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:3016",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note, I have a node backend.

Thanks :)